# Terraform AWS managed rules

Tags: terraform, config, rules

Terraform version : 11.11
  I am working on creating a custom config rule resource using below code,
 however the compliance_resource_types is getting set to
 **["AWS::EC2::Instance"]** instead of **["AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"]**.

Appreciate if someone can guide me on how to proceed.

```
`resource "aws_config_config_rule" "remove_sg_open_to_world" {
  name        = "security_group_not_open_to_world"
  description = "Rule to remove SG ports if open to public"

  source {
    owner             = "CUSTOM_LAMBDA"
    source_identifier = "arn:aws:lambda:${var.current_region}:xxxxxxxxx:function:remove_sg_open_to_world"

    source_detail {
      message_type = "ConfigurationItemChangeNotification"
    }
  }

  scope {
    compliance_resource_types = ["AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"]
  }

  depends_on = ["aws_config_configuration_recorder.config"]
```

Comment: Can you share the output of `aws configservice describe-config-rules --config-rule-names security_group_not_open_to_world` please? Also including the output of the Terraform plan when you are creating this resource would be helpful.

Comment: Could you also include the AWS Terraform provider version you are using too?

Comment: This is the output of describe-config-rules                                                                "Scope": {
                "ComplianceResourceTypes": [
                    "AWS::EC2::Instance"
                ]

Comment: And this is Terraform plan output  :>>>>>>
                  [0m[1maws_config_config_rule.security_group_not_open_to_world: Refreshing state... (ID: security_group_not_open_to_world)[0m
[0m[1maws_config_config_rule.security_group_not_open_to_world: Refreshing state... (ID: security_group_not_open_to_world)[0m <<<<<<<<<<